# Is Incomplete array type guaranteed to be able to store one element?

Tags: c, arrays, incomplete-type

***Incomplete array types*** are used in the famous ***[Struct hack](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=288)*** and they are allowed since c99 standard. prior to c99 standard these were not allowed. I was looking at the standard and I am unable to conclude:

Are Incomplete array types allowed outside a structure?(*All references I found in the standard C99: 6.7.2.1.15 talk about it as the last element in the structure*).

So is the following program allowed to compile as per the standard?

```
int array[];
int main(){return 0;}
```

Second part of my questions is, If this is allowed is `array` guaranteed to be able to store ***atleast one*** element of they type `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*is the following program allowed to compile as per the standard?*

Yes, as per:

> (C99, 6.9.2p5) "EXAMPLE 2 If at the end of the translation unit containing
>               int i[];
>   the array i still has incomplete type, the implicit initializer
>   causes it to have one element, which is set to zero on program
>   startup."

So

```
int array[];
int main(){return 0;}
```

is valid and equivalent to:

```
int array[1];
int main(){return 0;}
```

Note that it is OK only if `array` has (like above) external linkage as:

> (C99, 6.9.2p3) "If the declaration of an identifier for an object is a         tentative definition and has internal linkage, the declared type shall not be an incomplete type."

Comment: Ahh.. I noticed that just when you posted the answer.